# Script working on localhost but not on host server.

Tags: php, pdo

I have this script. It works all right in localhost but I have problems on host server.

```
$query="SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*,t4.*,t5.*,t7.asciiname as asciiname_t7, t8.asciiname as asciiname_t8,t9.*
         FROM anunturi t1 
         INNER JOIN tranzactie t2 ON t1.tranzactie = t2.id_tranzactie
         INNER JOIN tip_proprietate t3 ON t1.tip = t3.id_prop
         INNER JOIN anunt_descriere t4 ON t1.id_anunt = t4.ext
         INNER JOIN anunt_locatie t5 ON t1.id_anunt = t5.ext
         INNER JOIN zone t9 ON t5.zona = t9.id_zona
         INNER JOIN locatii t7 ON t5.judet = t7.admin1_code AND t7.feature_code='ADM1'
         INNER JOIN locatii t8 ON t5.oras = t8.geonameid
         WHERE t1.status=:arh ORDER BY t1.data DESC"; 




        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':arh', $arh, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $nr=$stmt->rowCount();
        //echo $nr;

if($nr>0)
  {
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result) 
        {
            if($result['tip']=='1')
            {
            $camere=" - ".$result['camere'];
            }
            else
            {
            $camere="";
            }
            if($result['special']=='0' && $_SESSION['privilegiu']=='2')      {
            $special="<a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'    onclick='special(this);'>special</a>";    
            $rest="<a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'   onclick='mod(this);'>Edit</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'  onclick='arhivare(this);'>Arhivare</a> "; 
            }
            else
            {
                if($_SESSION['privilegiu']=='2') {
                $special="<a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'   onclick='nespecial(this);'>normal</a>";
                $rest="<a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'   onclick='mod(this);'>Edit</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'   onclick='arhivare(this);'>Arhivare</a> ";
                }
                else
                {
                    $special="";
                    $rest="";
                }

            }
            $view[]="
            <tr>
            <td>".$result['id_anunt']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_tranzactie']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_prop'].$camere."</td>
            <td>".$result['asciiname_t7']." ".$result['asciiname_t8']." ".$result['den_zona']."</td>
            <td><input type='hidden' name='tip' id='i".$result['id_anunt']."' value='".$result['tip']."'><input type='hidden' name='tranz' id='e".$result['id_anunt']."' value='".$result['tranzactie']."'><a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."' class='view' value='".$result['id_anunt']."'   onclick='view(this);'>View</a> ".$rest.$special."</td>

            </tr>";

        }
   }
   else
    {   
$view[]="Nu exista oferte";
     }
    return $view;



}
```

I tested this script most on my localhost server and now I cannot use it.
I need it urgently.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quite frankly, nobody cares how urgent it is. *What* is not working exactly? Do you get any error messages? Have you done any debugging to figure out what "doesn't work" and what the difference to your local host is?

Comment: The script work fine on my wamp server but not working on host server.

Comment: First use ini_set('display_errors',1); top of your script and check if you get any error.

Comment: Yeah, we *got that*. It's not working on the server but is working on your localhost. Fine! Now: ***what*** is "not working"?! There's more than one thing in the code you show that could possibly be "not working" and there are about 3 gazillion causes for *why* it could possibility be "not working"!

Comment: I receive only "nu exista oferte"

Comment: and the number of rows is 0

Comment: You will need to post error information. Without it no one can help.

Comment: I don't recive any error

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple problems. The very first step is to check the mysql connection. Please check the connection parameters of mysql. You need to check:

```
mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
```

Also, I request you to post your error. This way, we will be able to help you much better.

Comment: I use a class and I define all parameters corectly because the script execute some functions from the class.